# How can I debug JPA projections content in Java?

Tags: java, spring-boot, debugging, jpa, projection

I'm using `JPA` `projections` in my project.
I have my `Projection` class which I can do getters without problem.

```
public interface ProjectionOP {

        String getName();
        
        LocalDate getDate();
//more attributes...
    }
```

If I print `projectionOp.getName();` it returns the value stored successfully.

Anyway, using debug mode, I can not view this value. If I use debug mode, it shows the following image, which I don't understand.

[image]

It is possible to view the value of attributes 'name' and 'date' of my projectionOP in debug mode?
I use STS IDE

Answer (score 0):

From your screenshot it seems like you are using Intellij. Is that correct?

If it is, you might try the suggestion regarding "Enable auto expressions in Variables view". and some other options described on https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-75922/Debugging-lazy-loaded-JPA-entity-attributes.

Comment: No, I'm using STS. I tried to do your answer in STS but I don't find it...